# Given character array,find kth non-repetitive character in one pass

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example. bacdbecdfb

First non-repetitive character would be 'a'  , second would be 'e' .

This was an interview question, I came up with using hashing to solve in 2 passes but the interviewer wanted it in one pass.
The hint he gave was that the maximum value of k can be 26.

Comment: k-th non-repetitive character
I mean considering only characters from a to z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just 26 possible character, So you can create an array of int of size 26 and in this way you can find all non repeated characters (by traversing your input and increase related character number). another iteration is needed to find their order (also repeated or not in second iterate is possible, in first iteration you just set the numbers for characters, e.g `a` is in position 0 and seen 1 time).

This known as counting sort.

**Edit:** for doing this just in one path you need add extra information to your sorting data, in fact you should add first visited time, So you will have array of struct:

```
struct data
{
   int firstVisitedPosition;
   int visitedCount;
}

data[26] sorter = new data[26];// --> initialize it as the way said above.
//Find all items in sorter with visitedCount=1 
var justOnes = sorter.Where(x=>x.visitedCount == 1).ToList();
Find minimum firstVisitedPosition:
var minPos = justOnes.Min(x=>x.firstVisitedPosition);
var minItem = justOnes.First(x=>x.firstVisitedPosition == minPos);
```

be careful `sorter` has length 26, and also justOnes has length ≤ 26 so iterating them 100 times doesn't related to input data iteration and has no problem, Also sorting or other actions all are constants.

Comment: Yes i did mention that in the post; the interviewer wanted it in a single pass

Comment: @vaibhav, I think you used hashing not hashmap:) I'll edit it.

Comment: @vaibhav, Edited to do so, Code is in c#.

Comment: This finds the first non-repetitive character, not the kth

Comment: @sourcedelica: You can replace justOnes.Min with JustOnes.findKth(whatever C# has for it or implement it) and that will give you K-th character. justOnes does need to be sorted by firstVisitedPosition though. 
The gist of any solution is storing both occurrence count and the first visited position.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution in C. Note that the input string is parsed only once.

**EDITED:**
Consider input: "bacdbecdfb"
Before parsing and charIndex are set to 0

**Iteration 1: [b]acdbecdfb**

increment count for 'b's position by 1. I am using charCnt to store the occurrence of all characters in input string alphabetically.
Index of 'b' in charCnt  is 1. (0 is for a, 1 for b and so on)

Also as an when we discover a new char, we need to record it as the final output depends on ordering of characters in the input string.
So I put position of 'b' in charIndex. ie. charIndex[0] = 1

charCnt = {0, 1, 0, 0,....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 0,....}

**Next iteration: b[a]cdbecdfb**

increment count for 'a's position in charCnt by 1. We have seen 'a' first time, so store index in charIndex.

charCnt = {1, 1, 0, 0,....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 0,....}

**Next iteration: ba[c]dbecdfb**

increment count for 'c's position in charCnt by 1. We have seen 'c' first time, so store index in charIndex.

charCnt = {1, 1, 1, 0,....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 2, 0, 0,....}

**Next iteration: bac[d]becdfb**

increment count for 'b's position in charCnt by 1. We have seen 'd' first time, so store index in charIndex.

charCnt = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 2, 3, 0,....}

**Next iteration: bacd[b]ecdfb**

increment count for 'b's position in charCnt by 1. We had seen 'b' before so dont update charIndex.

charCnt = {1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 2, 3, 0,....}

You can continue the same for rest of the string.

**In the end, you will get**

charCnt = {1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, ....}
charIndex = {1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0,....}

The **2nd for loop** is to scan the charIndex and find out for how many corresponding elements in charCnt have count 1. After we get kth such entry, we get the desired character.

```
char FindKthNonRepetitiveCharacter(char *string, int strlen, int k)
{
    int charCnt[26];    // stores the count of ewach character a,b,c,..
                        // in the input string
    int charIndex[26];  // stores the index for the character discovered
                        // in input string to refer to charCnt
    int i,charIndexCnt = 0;                 

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {               // init
        charCnt[i] = charIndex[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
        int index = string[i] - 'a';
        ++charCnt[index];

        if(charCnt[index] == 1) {  // only add newly discovered char.
            charIndex[charIndexCnt] = index;
            charIndexCnt++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < charIndexCnt && k > 0; i++) {
        if (charCnt[charIndex[i]] == 1)
            k--;
    }

    return (charIndex[i-1] + 'a');
}
```

Comment: Valid solution but I had a hard time understanding this
The similar variables names got me confused :)

Comment: i have added explanation for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array in which you store pairs: characters and how many times they occurred in the string up to now.
thus for you example playing through all steps:

```
[b]acdbqcdfb -> [(b, 1)]
b[a]cdbqcdfb -> [(b, 1), (a, 1)]
ba[c]dbqcdfb -> [(b, 1), (a, 1), (c, 1)]
bac[d]bqcdfb -> [(b, 1), (a, 1), (c, 1), (d, 1)]
bacd[b]qcdfb -> [(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 1), (d, 1)]
bacdb[q]cdfb -> [(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 1), (d, 1), (q, 1)]
bacdbq[c]dfb -> [(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 2), (d, 1), (q, 1)]
bacdbqc[d]fb -> [(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 2), (d, 2), (q, 1)]
bacdbqcd[f]b -> [(b, 2), (a, 1), (c, 2), (d, 2), (q, 1), (f, 1)]
bacdbqcdf[b] -> [(b, 3), (a, 1), (c, 2), (d, 2), (q, 1), (f, 1)]
```

Note that you don't add the letters in lexographical order, but in order of appearance, thus I needed to modify your example a bit. Finally you pass once the final array and count all letters that appear once in order of appearance. Your answer is the kth one. This solution passes only once the whole array and also for each letter traverses the array of letter occurrences once. Thus you pay 26 * n where n is the length of the array. However this solution is doing one pass, but is not rather better than yours. You can improve this complexity if you have a separate array of 26 of length and you store in it the index in the auxiliary array of each letter. This is the example of this second array at the end:
`a - 1, b - 0, c -2, d - 3. e - null, f - 5, g - null........q - 4, r - null...`. This array will enable you to find the needed index in a single operation, optimizing the solution to just n.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
        string s = "bacdbecdfb";

        List<char> nonRepeatedlist = new List<char>();

        List<char> repeatedList = new List<char>();

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (!nonRepeatedlist.Contains(c) && !repeatedList.Contains(c))
            {
                nonRepeatedlist.Add(c);
            }

            else
            {
                nonRepeatedlist.Remove(c);

                repeatedList.Add(c);
            }
        }

        if (k < nonRepeatedlist.Count)
            return nonRepeatedlist[k - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class kthnonrepetitive 
{
 public static void main(String argfs[])
  {
  boolean[] bool = new boolean[256];
  List<Character> list = new LinkedList<Character>(); 
  String s = "TOTALALZOXYX";
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
   {
   char c = s.charAt(i);
   if(bool[c])
   {
       list.remove(Character.valueOf(c));
   }
   else
   {
       bool[c]=true; 
       list.add(Character.valueOf(c));
   }
   }
   System.out.println(list.toArray()[1]);
 }
}
```

above program prints 2nd unique character in string.Let me know if you find anything wrong with above program.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a LinkedHashSet in Java to keep track of the characters that occur only once. For each element of the initial string add it to the set if not found, or remove it if already in the set. After the initial string is traversed iterate the set of unique chars to the k-th element.

Comment: I would point out that,if a character appears 2nd time,the it would be removed from the set.So if the same character appears for third time ,it would be treated as a new character.
However ,keeping track of character count to prevent that will work.
Or simply move it to end of set.

Comment: You are right, it is necessary to keep a second set with the duplicate entries that were identified so far.

Answer (score 0):

### This is an algorithm that find kth unique character in a single pass. It takes space O ( n).

```
unique_count := 0; // a variable to count unique character found so far
node *head := NULL; // head of the list
node *tail := NULL;

hashmap<char, node*> map; // This contains the mapping for characters when unique_count >= k

int input[26]; 
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (input[c % 26] == 0) // This char is first time appeared
    {
       unique_count++;
   if ( unique_count < k)
   {
       input[c % 26] += 26;
       continue;
   }
       //we found the kth unique chars so far, but it might not be, so store it in list
   else if (unique_count == k) 
   {
       node *n = new node(c);
       head = n;
       tail = n;
   }
   else
   {
       node *n = new node(c);
       tail->next = n;
       n->prev = tail;
       tail = n;
       map[c] = n;
   }
   input[c % 26] += 26;
    }
    else if( input[ c % 26] < 26)// This is 2nd time this char has appeared
    {
        if ( unique_count < k)
        unique_count--;
    else if ( unique_count == k)
    {
        delete(head);
        head = tail = NULL;
        unique_count --;
    }
    else
    {
    // delete that node
    node *temp = map[c];
            if (temp == tail)
            {
                tail->prev->next = NULL;
                tail = tail->prev;
            }
            else
            {
        temp -> prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
            }
    delete(temp);
    unique_count--;
    }
    input[c % 26] += 26;
    }
    // This is 3rd or more time this character has appeared. don't add to avoid integer overflow
    //end for loop
}

if ( head == NULL) return head->data;

else "No kth unique character"
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. The string is arbitrarily long and not just 26 characters.

Comment: @Vaibhav, I agree the string is arbitrarily long, but the distinct characters will be 26 only. So my solution is right. There might be some mistakes in the code, but the logic is right.

Comment: I am finding it quite difficult to figure out what your program is doing. I get the feeling that you are maintaining a k-sized doubly linked list.

I want to make a couple of observations:
1) You should explain the logic in brief so that people can understand large programs easily.
2) What is the purpose of input[26] ? Would be great if you add a comment for every datastructure like you did for the hashmap. Why are you incrementing its element by 26? Maybe you meant to increment it by 1?

Comment: 3) Making the indentation consistent would greatly help
4) I don't see any input string. 'c' seems to the character under consideration but no indication where its value came from. Also c%26 is not correct. It should be (c -'a'). You have 
used 'n' in for loop as well as a temporary variable when creating new node. Also if trying to delete the entire list, simply doing delete(head) does not destroy entire list. In the last if statememnt, I think you meant to say: if(head) or if(head!=NULL).

Answer (score 0):

We can even do it for running stream in O(n)(kth in terms of order of occurrence)

With two data structures:

1. Hash Map: To store the numbers already visited.
2. Doubly Linked List: To store the order of the number

Hash Map will point to the node of respective number in Doubly Linked List.

We can think of the following algorithm:

1. If the current number is not present in Hash Map(i.e number is not repeated) mark the number as visited in Hash Map and add the number to Linked List. (Maintain tail and kth pointer to the DLL)
2. Maintain the counter of numbers in DLL, when the counter becomes 'k' point the 'kth' pointer to tail.
3. If the current number is present in Hash Map and have pointer to node in DLL we have to remove the respective node from DLL, (have to maintain the value in hash map as we have visited the number and we need to remember it).

   i. If the number removed from DLL is smaller than number pointed by 'kth' pointer increase 'kth' pointer by 1.

   ii. If the number to be removed is greater than number pointed by 'kth' pointer no need to do any thing (keep 'kth' pointer where it was pointing).

'kth' pointer will always point to the 'kth' non repeating number in running stream.

As the numbers in stream are limited the hash will be of known limited size.

Answer (score 0):

An all-scenario encompassing solution but in python:
    # Program to return the kth non-repeating letter in a given string.

```
class RepeatingOrNot(object):

@classmethod
def non_repeating(cls, my_str, k):

    my_list = list(my_str)
    repeating = []
    non_repeating = list()

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] in repeating:

            continue

        else:

            for j in range(i+1, len(my_list)):

                if my_list[i] == my_list[j]:

                    repeating.append(my_list[i])
                    break

            else:
                non_repeating.append(my_list[i])
                continue

    if non_repeating:

        if not len(non_repeating) < k:

            return "The {0}th non-repeating letter in the " \
                   "input string is {1}".format(k, non_repeating[k - 1])

        else:

            return "There are not as many repeating characters in the" \
               " input string as user expected. " \
               "Please enter a valid value for k"

    else:

        return "The string does not have a single unique character." \
           "Please try a different string"


my_str = "ataaaaataaaaaaaaaaqwetaaataattttaaaaatttaaaarf"

my_str1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

my_str2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

my_str3 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678$9abcljldjljlauoejrlkjdljf "

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_obj = RepeatingOrNot()
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str, 5)
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str, 15)
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str1, 25)
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str1, 29)
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str2, 4)
    print test_obj.non_repeating(my_str3, 9)
```

[image]